# How do I rotate by a given pitch, roll, yaw, in the correct order using quaternions?

Tags: quaternion, panoramic

I have a panorama image mapped to a sphere which is rotated by some amount in the 3D scene.

I have the 2D image coordinates of a point on the panorama which I would like to mark in 3D by placing an object on the surface of the sphere at that point.

Because the image is equirectangular, the x and y (t&s for the old guys) correspond to the longitude and latitudes respectively.

Before using these image offsets which are scaled x:0->2pi, y:0->pi, I tried placing the object at the top of the sphere in 3D with its given rotation, using the code:

```
pitch, roll, yaw = Vector(sphere.rotation_euler)
yaw = yaw + radians(90) #- k.pt[0]*2*pi/pas[0]
pitch = pitch + radians(90) #- k.pt[1]*pi/pas[1]
            
x = cos(yaw)*cos(pitch); y = sin(yaw)*cos(pitch); z = sin(pitch)
mark_position = sphere.location + r * Vector((x,y,z))
```

I had to adjust the yaw and pitch by 90 degrees each so it corresponded with the top right corner of the panorama, which is where the offsets would then be subtracted from.

This worked when adjusting the pitch, roll, and yaw values of the sphere rotation separately, though when I tried a combined rotation it was applying the 90 pitch offset globally, i.e. after the roll/yaw:

[image: broken]

The marker has been lifted up along the global pitch axis to the top of the sphere from the red dot, when it should have moved to the circle..

Do I need to use quaternions to ensure the rotation order? How would I construct them from my offsets?
(The offsets did also succeed to place the marker in the correct place when only adjusting 1 of the pitch/roll/yaw so these are correct, just also wrong order for multiple rotations).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ali1234 on the irc for the solution. Turns out the quaternions had to multiply a unit vector (1,0,0), and with this there was no need to manually convert Euler rotation to direction vector:

```
S = sphere.rotation_euler.to_quaternion()
R = Euler((0, k.pt[1]*pi/pas[1]-radians(90), radians(90) - k.pt[0]*2*pi/pas[0])).to_quaternion()
local = S@R@Vector((1,0,0))
mark_position = sphere.location + r*local
```

Big ups!